# Does there exist a maximum $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for some prime $p$, $p_r=p +\sum_{n=1}^r 2^n$ is prime for $r=1,2,\ldots,m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers.

> Does there exist a maximum $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for some prime $p$, $p_r=p + \sum\limits_{n=1}^r 2^n$ is prime for $r=1,2,\ldots,m$?

There is most likely not a simple (or known) answer to this question, but I thought it was worthwhile to ask.

So far, I have concluded that $p$ must necessarily have $7$ as its first digit, that is, $p=7\,(\text{mod}\,10)$. If $p=x\,(\text{mod}\,10)$ for some $x\in\{1,3,9\}$, the process is cut short at some $p_k=5\,(\text{mod}\,10)$.

For example, if $p=1\,(\text{mod}\,10)$, \begin{align} p_1&=3\,(\text{mod}\,10) \\ p_2&=7\,(\text{mod}\,10) \\ p_3&=5\,(\text{mod}\,10)\Rightarrow p_3\notin \mathbb{P} \end{align}

For $p=7\,(\text{mod}\,10)$, we have
\begin{align} p_{4k}&=7\,(\text{mod}\,10) \\ p_{4k+1}&=9\,(\text{mod}\,10) \\ p_{4k+2}&=3\,(\text{mod}\,10) \\ p_{4k+3}&=1\,(\text{mod}\,10)\end{align}

for $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ (assume for simplicity that $p_0=p$).

Consider these two statements:
\begin{align} \exists p\in\mathbb{P}&:\;p_r=p + \sum_{n=1}^r 2^n\in\mathbb{P} \; \; \forall r\in\mathbb{N} \tag{1} \\ \exists m\in\mathbb{N}&:\;\text{for some $p\in\mathbb{P}$},\; p_r=p + \sum_{n=1}^r 2^n\in\mathbb{P} \; \; \forall r\in\{1,2,...,m\} \tag{2} \\ & \;\;\;\;\,\text{and}\; \forall p\in\mathbb{P},\; p_{m+1}\notin\mathbb{P} \end{align}

My strategy is simple: prove $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ false OR prove $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ false.

Through a bit of computerwork, I found that $m\ge 9$ for $p=2397347207$:

```
2397347207, 2397347209, 2397347213, 2397347221, 2397347237, 2397347269, 2397347333, 2397347461, 2397347717, 2397348229
```

If anyone can solve this, and/or point me toward helpful material, please post.

Comment: No, there is no upper bound. Conjecturally, we expect there to be arbitrarily large $m$. In particular, the set $(X, X + 2, X + 4 + 2, X + 8 + 4 + 2, ..., X + 2^{m+1} - 2)$ is an admissible ensemble for a prime configuration, and so the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuple conjecture implies that there are infinitely many $X$ such that every element in the set is prime.

Comment: @davidlowryduda  Fascinating.  I will need more time to review this (my mathematical knowledge is quite dismal). Please feel free to post this as an answer if you deem it worthy.  Thank you.

Comment: @davidlowryduda is this relevant at all? [https://www.academia.edu/26680017/The_Hardy-Littlewood_Prime_k-tuple_Conjecture_is_False](https://www.academia.edu/26680017/The_Hardy-Littlewood_Prime_k-tuple_Conjecture_is_False)

Comment: Probably the best result you may apply (so far) is [Green-Tao theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%E2%80%93Tao_theorem). Specifically the generalisation that

<< Given any integer-valued polynomials $P_1$,..., $P_r$ in one unknown $x$ all with constant term $0$, there are infinitely many integers $y$, $x$ such that $y + P_1(x)$, ..., $y + P_r(x)$ are simultaneously prime.>>

In this case $P_1(x)=x$, $P_2(x)=x+x^2$, $P_3(x)=x+x^2+x^3$, ..., $P_r(x)=x+x^2+x^3+...+x^r$. It could happen that $x=2$ and $y$ is a prime, thus no maximum $m$.

Comment: gp-code for $p=2397347207$: `p=2397347207;for(m=1,1000,pr=p+sum(n=1,m,2^n);if(ispseudoprime(pr),print1(pr", ")))`. For $p=3559$ minimum $m$ is $14640$.

Comment: @C.Melton It should be pointed out that it is only a cojecture that a prime tuple can be found for arbitary $r$. A proof of this result will be out of reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conjecture that the answer to your question is positive is very strong.

Indeed, remark that $p_r=p + \sum\limits_{n=1}^r 2^n=p+2^{r+1}-2$ for each $r=1,2,\ldots,m$.

> $\exists p\in\mathbb{P} :\;p_r=p + \sum_{n=1}^r 2^n\in\mathbb{P} \; \; \forall r\in\mathbb{N}\tag{1}$

If $\Bbb P$ is the set of prime numbers then (1) is false. Namely, $p_{p-1}=p+2^p-2$ is divisible by $p$ by Fermat little theorem.

Thus the only way to have the positive answer is to have infinitely many distinct prime numbers $p$ such that both $p$ and $p+2$ are prime, that is they are prime twins.

> So far, I have concluded that $p$ must necessarily have $7$ as its first digit, that is, $p=7\,(\text{mod}\,10)$.

Given $m$, we can obtain a family of similar restrictions on $p=p_0$ as follows. Let $\Bbb P_2=\{3, 5, 11, 13,\dots \}$ be the set of prime numbers $q$ such that $2$ has order $q-1$ in the (cyclic) multiplicative group $\Bbb Z^*_q$ of the finite field $\Bbb Z_q=\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z$. Let $q\le m+2$ and $q<p$ be any element of $\Bbb P_2$. Then among the residues of $p_0,\dots, p_m$ we met all residues modulo $q$ but $p-2$. Since all $p_r$ are prime, this is possible only if the only missed residue is zero, that is if $p-2$ is divisible by $q$. That is $p-2$ is divisible by a product $\prod \{q\in\Bbb P_2: q\le m+2,\, q<p\}$.